# How to make link highlighted in email through mailto

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Very simple question: I have

```
 $('#email-link').attr('href', 'mailto:?subject=Checkout%20My%20Survey%20Results&body=' + encodeURIComponent(window.location.href));
```

and I want the link that is the body of the email to be clickable. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: You mean `encodeURIComponent('<a href="' + window.location.href + '">' + window.location.href + '</a>')`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just set the HTML of the anchor tag to the body of the email.

```js
var emailBody = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean justo purus, iaculis id cursus quis, consectetur vel arcu. Sed iaculis sagittis elit, non tristique ex malesuada non. Etiam elementum lectus quis nunc efficitur blandit. Mauris luctus nunc a quam euismod, sit amet maximus tortor venenatis. Aliquam tempus convallis magna. Aenean nec lorem pellentesque, sollicitudin massa quis, ultrices lacus. Vestibulum egestas magna libero, vel facilisis arcu viverra eu. Nullam eget rhoncus mi, vel volutpat eros. Phasellus iaculis urna quam, vel porttitor dolor feugiat eu. Ut nec tincidunt nulla. Duis imperdiet molestie massa, id placerat ligula aliquet quis. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Morbi blandit, eros eget pretium porta, felis mi blandit nunc, at malesuada metus lorem non nunc. Integer sollicitudin libero at ante accumsan molestie. Morbi in ultricies magna. Sed et ullamcorper purus."
$('#email-link').attr('href', 'mailto:?subject=Checkout%20My%20Survey%20Results&body=' + encodeURIComponent(emailBody))
.html(emailBody);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="email-link"></a>
```

Comment: Hmmm that is making the link be the inner text of the <a> tag

Comment: It's still the href if you hover over or click it. The inner html of the anchor tag has no influence on where the anchor will take you.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding anchor tag and set the href of anchor tag as encoded uri of window.location.href

```
'mailto:?subject=Checkout%20My%20Survey%20Results&body=<a href="' + encodeURIComponent(window.location.href) + '">Survey Link</a>'
```